# Hibernate throws strange error: Class is not mapped

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

this is the error

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Payment is not mapped [select p from Payment p]
```

I don't understand how come this error is thrown, the class should be mapped as I will show you briefly. I have a very basic config, like this one: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/ch01.html

I have tried to add the mapping definition into hibernate.cfg.xml and I have also tried to add it programmatically. Neither of them worked. Could anybody tell me what am I missing here? (it is not the first time I put together a Hibernate project)

this is the hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/paymentsdatabase</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">xxx</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">xxx</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

    <!--  <mapping class="com.lsyh.swati.zk.model.Payment"/> -->
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

the database connection is working fine, I have tested that

this is the static initializer in my HibernateUtil

```
static {
    try {

        // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
        // config file.
        sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration()
            .addPackage("com.lsyh.swati.zk.model")
            .addAnnotatedClass(Payment.class)
            .configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Log the exception. 
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed. " + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}
```

and this is where I use the sessionFactory in the PaymentIODb class:

```
public static List<Payment> readDataFromDb(){
        StatelessSession session = StoreHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openStatelessSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("select p from Payment p");
        List<Payment> payments = query.list();
        session.close();
        return payments;
}
```

this is the stack trace

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Payment is not mapped [select p from Payment p]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:255)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3056)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2945)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:688)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:544)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:228)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:112)
    at com.lsyh.swati.zk.controller.PaymentIODb.readDataFromDb(PaymentIODb.java:35)
    at com.lsyh.swati.zk.controller.PaymentIODb.resolveVariable(PaymentIODb.java:20
```

Comment: Can you show the `Payment` class? How it's annotated?

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446048/hibernate-table-not-mapped-error

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I'd expect one of two things to be the reason:

1. either you don't have Payment listed in your hibernat.cfg.xml or where ever you config your mapped classes.
2. another reason might be the confusion between javax...Entity and org.hibernate....Entity. Make sure you use the first one.

Comment: Well, Sir, the @Entity annotation _was_ actually org.hibernate... I have changed it to javax.persistence.Entity. The result list is still empty though. it is empty because the table name (and also the column names) are not translated from camelCase to camel_case (underlines as in the database) . If you could hint me on this one ... Thanks anyway

Comment: you can simply use the @Table(name="camel_case") on your entity class

Comment: Do I have to list my annotated model classes in hibernate.cfg.xml or is this use case only when you have xml mapping?

Answer (score 30):

Instead of

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select p from Payment p");
```

try this

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select p from " + Payment.class.getName() + " p");
```

Comment: Tahnks, this eliminates the error! Although the returned list is empty and there is a WARN in the log: `2011-12-15 19:39:39,246 [http-8080-2] WARN  org.hibernate.hql.QuerySplitter - no persistent classes found for query class: select p from com.lsyh.swati.zk.model.Payment p`

Comment: check in your Payment class Entity should be coming from javax.persistence.Entity and Table should be coming from javax.persistence.Table. Dont use the annotation from hibernate package

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I accepted Jens' answer because that had the same result but it made me somewhat clear what is the problem. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Could you give me an explanation why this works. I met the same issue and got my code work by using this solution?

Comment: Hats off to you! I was breaking my head on this for hours. This is a simple solution, every hibernate project I ever worked with had this technique and yet no one documented a solution for this problem so well.

Comment: Can any body explain why this works? It solve my problem when using select statement ,  though I directly use entity name at delete statement works fine.

Comment: +, It help me too. Please present any explanation.

Answer (score 3):

uncomment the commented mapping code in hibernate.cfg.xml config file

```
<!--  <mapping class="com.lsyh.swati.zk.model.Payment"/> -->

change it to

<mapping class="com.lsyh.swati.zk.model.Payment"/>
```

for more information refer this link

http://www.javabeat.net/tips/112-configure-mysql-database-with-hibernate-mappi.html

Comment: OP is using annotated class so why to uncomment it from config file ?

Comment: eventhough annotated class, need to map in the configuration file as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Your entity bean is not getting registered i guess.
Set proper root package name of your entity beans in packagesToScan property.
Also check your @Table(name="name_of_your_table").

Answer (score 1):

Although accepted answer is correct, would like to add context to the first part of the answer.

Inside of your config.java (or whatever you have named your application configuration file in packages), ensure you have properly configured your entityScan:

```
package com.example.config;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;

@EntityScan("com.example.entities")
```

However, if you like our team have moved your objects into their own packages, you may want to allow for a scan of all package folders:

```
@EntityScan("com.example.*")
```

Now that not all entities are in the entities folder specifically.

Answer (score 0):

For me, my Class was not listed in my Persistence.xml file in the class section.

Do that to solve the ish. or wherever your classes are listed.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem , instead @Entityt mapping i
I used following code for getting records
private @Autowired HibernateTemplate incidentHibernateTemplate;

```
    List<Map<String, Object>> list = null;
            list = incidentHibernateTemplate.execute(new HibernateCallback<List<Map<String, Object>>>() {

            @Override
            public List<Map<String, Object>> doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException {
                Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * from table where appcode = :app");
                    query.setParameter("app", apptype);
                query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
                return query.list();

                }
            });
```

I used following code for update

```
private @Autowired HibernateTemplate incidentHibernateTemplate;
Integer updateCount = 0;

    updateCount = incidentHibernateTemplate.execute((Session session) -> {
        Query<?> query = session
                    .createSQLQuery("UPDATE  tablename SET key = :apiurl, data_mode = :mode WHERE apiname= :api ");
          query.setParameter("apiurl", url);
          query.setParameter("api", api);
          query.setParameter("mode", mode);
            return query.executeUpdate();
        }
    );
```