# Hibernate Criteria list always return 0 items

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Function in my DAO (findByUsername) is always returning 0 rows no matter if I change the entity class, even after removing annotation from the entity there is no exception, just 0 rows. This code is implemented in the spring based app according to some examples I have found.

**DAO**:

```
@Repository("userDao")
public class UserDao extends CustomHibernateDaoSupport {
    public void save(User user) {
        getHibernateTemplate().save(user);
    }

    public void delete(User user) {
        getHibernateTemplate().delete(user);
    }

    public User findByUsername(String username) throws DataNotFoundException {
        Session session = getSession();
        Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(User.class);
        System.out.println(username);
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("username", username));
        crit.setMaxResults(1);

        List<User> users = crit.list();
        System.out.println(users);
        if (users.size() < 1) {
            throw new DataNotFoundException();
        }


        return users.get(0);
    }
}
```

**ENTITY**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    private Integer id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean active;
    private String activationCode;
    private Date createdAt;
    private String email;
    private Set<Wall> walls = new HashSet<Wall>();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "username", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Column(name = "password")
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Column(name = "active")
    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    @Column(name = "activation_code")
    public String getActivationCode() {
        return activationCode;
    }

    public void setActivationCode(String activationCode) {
        this.activationCode = activationCode;
    }

    @Column(name = "created_at", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    @Column(name = "email")
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_has_walls", joinColumns = { 
            @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, 
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "wall_id", 
                    nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    public Set<Wall> getWalls() {
        return walls;
    }

    public void setWalls(Set<Wall> walls) {
        this.walls = walls;
    }
}
```

Comment: Obvious question: Is there _data_ in your database? Also you can use `crit.uniqueResult()` for returning a single element instead of `crit.list().get(0);`

Comment: What is the SQL being generated by Hibernate? Sometimes the generated SQL will not match your expectation of what it should be doing. Run that SQL by itself using a standalone tool to help debug the problem.

Comment: Turn on SQL logging setting 'hibernate.show_sql' to 'true' and inspect the generated query. Try to run the query against your database manually

Comment: Getting from HQL gives me: User is not mapped [FROM User]. I have one row in users table.

Comment: Seems like hibernate did not map my classes, changing it to scan entire package with entities turned on into exceptions at runtime. ie. Unknown mappedBy in: com.walladverts.model.entities.Post.user, referenced property unknown: com.walladverts.model.entities.User.user

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524767/hibernate-throws-strange-error-class-is-not-mapped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change import declaration to

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
```

instead of hibernate. 
User entity class was not imported.