# How to return only one column in Hibernate?

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate

I want to return only one column from table. This is my DAO:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public String getUri() {

        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("uri from Templates WHERE state=1").toString();
    }
```

Uri is a column.
Domain:

```
    public String getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    public void setUri(String uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }
```

Console says:

```
 Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!
```

The second version:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public String getUri() {

        return (String) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("select uri from TEMPLATES WHERE state=1")
                .uniqueResult();
    }
```

Console:

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: TEMPLATES is not mapped [select uri from TEMPLATES WHERE state=1]
```

Comment: I think you forgot to call `getResultList()` or `list` on Query object. And return `List<Object>` instead of `String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SELECT clause is missing:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public String getUri() {

        Query q = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("SELECT uri FROM Templates WHERE state=1");

        List l = q.list();

        //guess you know there's only one result?
        return l.get(0).toString();
    }
```

More info in: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2448422

Comment: Look at the topic please

Comment: Really? Is this 'accepted' answer? It just returns query string instead of query result.

Comment: Yeah, lol, accepted before correct version was introduced according to my answer and comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the class/field names, not the table/column names.  Also, the query won't return a list of instances of your class for that table, but rather an array.  Also, put a `select` in your query.  I believe that exception means your hql is broken.

Comment: But uri - is field name. Look.

Comment: Now it says:`TEMPLATES is not mapped [select uri from TEMPLATES WHERE state=1]`

Comment: @John, if you still have this problem, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524767/hibernate-throws-strange-error-class-is-not-mapped

Answer (score 0):

As you added `select`, then call `list` method on your `Query`. And get first result from the list if you want to get only first one.