# Load different Entities from a single table with a column as discriminator

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, annotations

I have the following table with 3 types of people, boy, man and woman:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person(
  id int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  type VARCHAR(100),
  name VARCHAR(100),
  description VARCHAR(2000),
  PRIMARY KEY (id) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO person (id, type, name, description) VALUES(1, 'child', 'Omar', '');
INSERT INTO person (id, type, name, description) VALUES(2, 'man', 'john doe', '');
INSERT INTO person (id, type, name, description) VALUES(3, 'woman', 'jennifer lopez', '');
```

And I have the following classes:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class PersonEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")      
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="name")        
    private String name;

    @Column(name="description")         
    private String desciption;

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public final Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public final void setId(final Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public final String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public final void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the desciption
     */
    public final String getDesciption() {
        return desciption;
    }

    /**
     * @param desciption the desciption to set
     */
    public final void setDesciption(final String desciption) {
        this.desciption = desciption;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class ChildEntity extends PersonEntity {

    //Value child
    @Column(name="type")        
    private String type;

    /**
     * @return the type
     */
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    /**
     * @param type the type to set
     */
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class ManEntity extends PersonEntity {

    //Value man
    @Column(name="type")        
    private String type;

    /**
     * @return the type
     */
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    /**
     * @param type the type to set
     */
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }   
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class WomanEntity extends PersonEntity {

    //Value man
    @Column(name="type")        
    private String type;

    /**
     * @return the type
     */
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    /**
     * @param type the type to set
     */
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }       
}
```

My question is how can I make my list of loaded classes directly discriminated by the kind of person with annotations. Ie to recover all women, just come to me kind of woman. I do so because they have all three the same attributes and do not want to make just one person class and method search by type.

---

**I found the solution:**

```
@Entity  
@Table(name = "person")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class PersonEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")      
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="name")        
    private String name;

    @Column(name="description")         
    private String desciption;

    @Column(name="type", insertable = false, updatable = false)         
    private String type;    

    //getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@DiscriminatorValue("child")
public class ChildEntity extends PersonEntity { 

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@DiscriminatorValue(value="man")
public class ManEntity extends PersonEntity {

}

@Entity  
@Table(name = "person")
@DiscriminatorValue(value="woman")
public class WomanEntity extends PersonEntity {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
@Entity  
@Table(name = "person")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class PersonEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")      
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="name")        
    private String name;

    @Column(name="description")         
    private String desciption;

    @Column(name="type", insertable = false, updatable = false)         
    private String type;    

    //getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@DiscriminatorValue("child")
public class ChildEntity extends PersonEntity { 

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@DiscriminatorValue(value="man")
public class ManEntity extends PersonEntity {

}

@Entity  
@Table(name = "person")
@DiscriminatorValue(value="woman")
public class WomanEntity extends PersonEntity {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use inheritance strategy InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE. For that u need to annotate your PersonEntity class as follows:

```
@Entity  
@Table(name = "person")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type",discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING) 
public abstract class PersonEntity {
...
}
```

I think you need to declare it abstract as well, but I'm not 100% sure.

Then your subclasses need following annotation:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="child")  
public class ChildEntity extends PersonEntity {
...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="man")  
public class ManEntity extends PersonEntity {
...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="woman")  
public class WomanEntity extends PersonEntity {
...
}
```

Comment: I was just trying something like that, but not work for me, I always returns an empty list.

Comment: How does your query looks like?

Comment: Does not leave any query in the log,
I suppose that no query does not run.

Comment: But how do you load them? Can you post your code for fetching the entities?

Comment: In my genericDaoImpl  @Override
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 public final <T> listAll<T> listar(final Class<T> type) throws PersistenceException {
  Session sesion = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  final Criteria crit = sesion.createCriteria(type);
  List<T> resultado = null;
  try {
   resultado = crit.list();
  } catch (HibernateException ex) {
   throw new PersistenceException(ex);
  }
  return resultado;
 }

Comment: Yes. But I returned three empty lists, children, men and women. And in the log does not leave any query.

Comment: I added @DiscriminatorOptions(force = true), but not working. I changed the criteria for implementing this:  public final <T> List<T> listar(final Class<T> type) throws PersistenceException {
  Session sesion = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  List<T> resultado = null;  
  resultado = sesion.createQuery("FROM " +  type.getSimpleName()).list();
  return resultado;
 } and throws me the following exception: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: ChildEntity is not mapped [FROM ChildEntity]

Comment: Did you list the entities in your hibernate config? (see [this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8524836/3843672/) )

Comment: This is my setup:     <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.company.proyect.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

Comment: What about the second suggestion in the above link? Do you use javax...Entity?

Comment: I found the solution, I have to put the "table" annotation also child, man and woman. And in the attribute type insertable = false, updatable = false